# Not able to import large flat file into SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, bcp

I have an 18GB flat file (40,000,000 records), with fixed column widths (no field terminators), which I would like to read into a SQL Server 2008 R2 table. In addition to the text file with the data, I was given an Excel document with the field names and lengths. There are 270 fields with 465 total characters per record (per row). Using bcp I have created an fmt file, which looks fine to me.

```
10.0

270

1   SQLCHAR  2  1  ""  1  TitleCode   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

2   SQLCHAR  2 12  ""  2  FamilyID    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

3   SQLCHAR  2 12  ""  3  LocationID  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

etc.

In SQL Server I want to use this fmt file to read the data into the table:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Customer2_noId

    FROM 'C:\Uploads\dataFile_MICX\dataFile_MICX_Copy.txt'

    WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\Users\kriss\SqlScripts\Customer2_noId-n.fmt');

GO
```

Error Messages from SQL Server:

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
>
> The bulk load failed. The column is
>   too long in the data file for row 1,
>   column 1. Verify that the field
>   terminator and row terminator are
>   specified correctly.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked
>   server "(null)" reported an error. The
>   provider did not give any information
>   about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
> Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB
>   provider "BULK" for linked server
>   "(null)".

I have tried changing the filed terminator for the last field to "\r" and "\r\n"
I have tried adding an extra field at the bottom:

```
271   SQLCHAR  0 0  "\r\n"  271  dummy SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Makes no difference.

I have not been able to find anything on line which helps. (Extra blank line in fmt file is suggested, but that doesn't fix it. I think the data file has line terminators, because if I use the Excel data import tool, I see consistent-length lines.

Can someone help?
Thanks,  Kriss

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Without hands-on work, I can only offer some ideas and suggestions:

First off, you need to determine whether there is a row terminator or not -- there may be no /r /n, char(13)+char(10), null-terminator, or whatever in the file.

Try and get a copy of the file, one that only contains the first 10, 100, maybe 1000 rows to work with. (Creating this would make it much easier to find the presence or absence of row terminators). There are a large number of such editors out there; I have used LTFViewr in the past, not sure what version they're up to now.

I recall BCP being very fussy about it's row and column delimiters. If something didn't match up, it'd just fail. (I recall having to tweak the odd first or last line in a file to get BCP to work.)

Have you considered using Intergration Services (SSIS)? It is much more flexible and adaptable, though it does represent a significantly different learning curve. It has the big advantage that Microsoft has improved it over the 2005 version, where I doubt they've even done a code review on BCP in the past six years.

Comment: Thank you. I did start using SSIS. In the Flat File connection manager, I set the row width to the expected width, and the final character on each line is a red box, so I assume that is a special character - maybe CRLF, maybe not... (Also, when I did data import in Excel, I also saw that all lines are the same width.) Thanks for your help - I'll just go with SSIS. BCP looked like it was so straightforward, but...

Comment: One of the plusses of SSIS is that it can figure out a lot of things "under the hood" -- such as what the row delimiter is.